# ¿Como paso una función de python atraves de django?

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo en la programacion, y me he visto envuelto en una tutoria de desarrollo web en django, poseo conocimientos intermedios de python y algunas GUIS como tkinter. Quiero hacer una página web donde el usuario intruzca datos y estos sean enviados a un script de python que los procese para luego retornar la respuesta, intente de varios metodos, desde usar js hasta php, tambien usando los {{}} pero no logro entender como pasar datos desde in input HTML y estos datos procesarlos con python y luego retornarlos hacia html para asi tambien darles un estilo usando css, adjunto un video que use como referencia, que funciona pero no del todo, los datos se quedan estancados sin importar cuantas veces refresque la pagina, y me gustaria saber si hay otros metodos de hacerlo. Adjunto el video:

https://youtu.be/ERMRVORGvZM

Presento un ejemplo usando tkinter de como, según yo, podria funcionar, cabe destacar que es solo a manera de representación.

principal.py

```
import tkinter as tk

from otroarchivo import ask, boton

root=tk.Tk()
ask(root)

btn=tk.Button(root, text='soy un boton', command=boton)

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

otroarchivo.py

```
import tkinter as tk 

def ask(master=None):

    global dato, pregunta

    info=tk.Label(master, text='Ingrese su nombre')

    info.pack()

    pregunta=tk.Entry(master)

    pregunta.pack() 




def boton():
    dato=pregunta.get()

    print(dato)
```

Al correrlo, pide los datos desde un archivo y los presenta desde otro que manda a llamar a ese archivo, no es algo necesario al momento de usar tkinter pero algo asi me gustaria hacer en django, espero se comprendiera.

De antemano muchas gracias por ayudar a un novato :D

> Cita en bloque

Cita en bloque

Comment: recuerda que toda web funciona en base a HTML, css y JS. Si tu quieres hacer una validación de algo con python tendrás que enviarlo aun endpoint que hayas creado y recibir esos datos y procesarlos, lo puedes hacer usando AJAX

Comment: Muchas gracias por resonder! con el tema de AJAX lo usaria para establecer la comunicacion entre mi script de python externo y las views en django, cierto?

Comment: Pues más o menos, la view se renderiza y deja de una view y pasa a ser un html normal, con ayuda de JS haces una petición http hacia una ruta por ejemplo `/validar` y en tus rutas de django haces toda la lógica